# Could this be a Normal Map?

Tags: modeling, baking

Is the Image below a Normal Map or it is geometry?

I would like to know if an effect like that is possible to reach with Normal Map or maybe even multiple Maps.

[image]

Comment: To me the large raised area looks like geometry since it is casting a shadow on the rest of the mesh.  The small details (rivets, seam between panels, etc.) are hard to tell but could probably be created with a normal map.

Comment: More advanced techniques like [parallax mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_mapping) or using a [displacement map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping) can achieve high-quality results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, the big extruding portion is geometry.

In the general case, it very much depends on how close you look at it and at what angle.

With a normal map you always see all faces of a detail. From some angles it can seem wrong since they are facing away from you.

Here we have some geometry represented by... geometry and a normal map. Normal map below. Can you tell wich one is the normal map? Yes, of course you can. But this is realy up close. Still, if you are rendering a space ship and are flying by it's side, go for geometry.

[image: normal map example]